# Why ActiveRecord `includes` doesn't bring duplicated records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

If I have two models and one junction model:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :groups
end

class GroupMembership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group

  # has attributes for date_joined and role
end
```

If more than one Group has a reference to User, why when I do:

`User.includes(:groups)` I don't get duplicated records? That is, how does Rails figures out to not include more than once for each user?

Answer (score 0):

Method `includes` is generally used for eager loading, in your case groups related for users. In this case it would use two queries: loading users and loading groups (let you examine the sql queries shown). If you would like to see duplicated records use the join explicitly:

```
User.joins(:groups)
```